# Как решить проблему с запросом в mysql golang?

Tags: mysql, golang

Здравствуйте, уже какой день мучаюсь с проблемой.
Подключаюсь к базе Mysql

```
  db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user:password@/")
  defer db.Close()
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
```

Потом я хочу проверить на совпадения в базе, выполняю код:

```
  key := 1545
      var user_key string
      err = db.QueryRow("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_key=?", key).Scan(&user_key)
      switch {
      case err == sql.ErrNoRows:
        log.Printf("No user with that key.")
      case err != nil:
        log.Fatal(err)
      default:
        fmt.Println("User key, ", user_key)
      }
```

Таблица mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `user_id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_key` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_login` VARCHAR(35) NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
)
```

Вот что возращает в лог:

```
2016/06/10 10:17:54 sql: expected 3 destination arguments in Scan, not 1
```

Подскажите как решить проблему, в гугл ходил и не один раз!

Comment: Плохо ходили. У вас в таблице `users` сколько колонок? Три?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем Google, когда есть godoc.org? Поведение [`(*Row).Scan()`](https://godoc.org/database/sql#Row.Scan) схоже с поведением [`(*Rows).Scan`](https://godoc.org/database/sql#Rows.Scan). И собственно:

> The number of values in dest must be the same as the number of columns in Rows.

Что значит: количество аргументов должно быть равно количеству колонок в таблице. Иными словами

```
var userId int
var userKey int
var userLogin string
err = db.QueryRow("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_key=?", key).
    Scan(&userId, &userKey, &userLogin)
```

Или соответственно

```
var userKey int
err = db.QueryRow("SELECT users.user_key FROM users WHERE user_key=?", key).
    Scan(&userKey)
```